# how to detect duration a WebClient.DownloadData() takes to complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

how can i tell how long a:

```
objWebClient.DownloadData(strURL)
```

takes to complete?

i wish there was a property that contained this info but i couldn't find one...

Comment: Are you really trying to just get the time to download (in which case use the 2 answers below) or are you trying to get a progress time (including xxx minutes remaining).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
webClient.DownloadData(...);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Download took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

If you're using synchronous APIs, it's really easy. It's trickier with asynchronous APIs, but you'd just need to pass around the stopwatch in your state. Again, that's pretty easy if you use an anonymous method or lambda expression for your event handler, as it can capture the local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class - start it before the call and stop it after the call:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

objWebClient.DownloadData(strURL)

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed; // ts now holds the duration
```